# Header redirects to the same page, not pages specified

Tags: php, html, wamp

I've read through a lot of answers on this site already, but all of the solutions have never helped this issue. I have code to redirect a page using PHP based on the form data they submit for a survey project. The header should redirect to another page based on the user selection from the drop down list. All of them are stored in the www directory on my localhost WAMP server. The problem is, the page does not redirect to the page I specify in the header redirect, but instead just reloads the current page. I need it to redirect to the pages specified in the headers.

Here is the PHP:

```
    <?php
    session_start();

    if(isset($_POST['post'])) {
    $_SESSION['maintasked'] = $_POST['maintask'];
    $_SESSION['dated'] = $_POST['date'];
    $_SESSION['named'] = $_POST['name'];
    session_write_close();

    if(!empty($_POST['name']))
    {
    switch($_POST['maintask']) {

    case "Pre Cabinet":
    header('Location: /Tier2PreCabinet.php');
    exit;
    break;

    case "At Cabinet":
    header('Location: /Tier2AtCabinet.php');
    exit;
    break;

    case "Post Cabinet":
    header('Location: /Tier2PostCabinet.php');
    exit;
    break;

    }
   }
  }
?>
```

And here is the HTML:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset = "utf-8">
<title>Advanced RV Time Records</title>
</head>
<body>

<h2>Advanced RV Time Capsule</h2>

<!-- This form grabs today's date from the JS run at page load and allows the user to change it if necessary -->
<p>Enter the date of the day the work was done.</p>
<form method="post" action="<?=$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>">
        <input type="date" id="theDate" value="" name ="date">

<!-- This form has the user select the name they will be working under. Must be completed. -->  
<p id ="name" name="named">Enter the name of the worker performing the task. </p>

<select id="workers" name="name">
<option value =null></option>
<option>Brian</option>
<option>Mike G.</option>
<option>Anthony</option>
<option>Tom</option>
<option>Joe</option>
<option>Deury</option>
<option>Chris Puetzfeld</option>
<option>Chris Piercy</option>
<option>Frank</option>
</select>


<!-- This form has the user select the task they will be working on.-->
<p>Enter the main task that the worker will be doing</p>

<select id ="MainTask" name ="maintask">
<option id ="1">Pre Cabinet</option>
<option value ="2">At Cabinet</option>
<option value ="3">Post Cabinet</option>
</select>
<input type ="submit" value="Continue On">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: "Can you find the bug" questions [are not good questions for Stack Overflow](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253787/are-there-legitimate-fix-my-code-questions?cb=1#253788). Make sure you a brief, but **specific statement of the problem**, telling us precisely what is wrong. "It doesn't work" is not a problem statement.

Comment: I apologize, I tried specifying the existing problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Select boxes pass the value in the value attribute if set, not the text. On your select box, your first option has no value attribute, so the text will be submitted. However on your second and third options, you have a value of `2` and `3` which is what will be submitted. Your php code is looking for the text values, not the number values that will be submitted.

You can either change `id="1"` on your first option to `value="1"` and in your php look for the values `1`, `2` or `3`. Or you can remove the `value` from options `2` and `3` and the text should submit.

Comment: I have alleviated this issue,but the page still redirects to itself.

Comment: Well, how about instead of doing an actual header call, you echo out where it should be redirecting to. Then put a default case on the switch that says `echo "Case not found: {$_POST['maintask']}";`. This is pretty standard debugging. If something isn't working, echo out as much as possible.

Comment: Also, is it possible that you are directing to another page properly but that page is redirecting back for some reason?

Comment: Thanks for that echo suggestion, I'm really new to PHP and web design in general so I'm still picking things up. The page isn't outputting anything through echo, so there has to be something wrong with the server or PHP configuration itself. Thanks!

Comment: By the way, the pages the headers redirected to did not contain any redirects back to the page the header was on.

Comment: Did you add in the default case to the switch? That will tell you what value `maintask` has if no cases were matched.